# Can I save my Tweaks, themes, icons, customisation, softwares etc. like a backup and restore them if i do fresh install?

Tags: lubuntu, backup

I did a lot of work today and enhanced the look of my Lubuntu 13.10.

I also installed  a lot of packages, like Numix icon theme from their PPA, downloaded icons and changed the taskbar color, size etc.

Now I want to save that all as a backup so that, if I have any errors, I can restore my customizations.

Comment: Yes, of course! See this: http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps/     You'd better back up the /etc folder as well (for your network connections, etc).

Comment: @Reza It would be a good idea to post this as an answer!

Comment: but it only trandsfers packages :-( not the tweaks

Comment: no it is not dupe!!! That answer does not cover, 'how to backup my tweaks like panel sixe, panel color, theme etc.' ----Mods please do something!

Comment: There's nothing for us to do, the question is still open.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the setting for the installed applications are stored in the folders in your home folder that start with a dot like .config or .mozilla, etc. So If you back up and move them to a new computer, the applications work just like before. This is for example what I did with my Firefox  and XFCE desktop settings when I moved to a new laptop.

There are a few more things to consider:

1-You should back up the list of installed packages as well, as explained in the link in my comment above.

2-Some of your "system" settings are not restored in the home folder, for example the network (ethernet, wifi, etc) and their passwords are stored in /etc/NetworkManager/ so you may want to back them up as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's more to it than .config and such from your home dir. The login screen wallpaper is somewhere like /usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers, and if you customized the bootloader it's yet somewhere else. I wonder how people scoop stuff up for "themes" like this one -- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/windows-xp-theme-lubuntu

Is there a script or package that cooks up "themes" that could be used to back up ones wallpapers, bootloader screens, login screens, fonts, icons, etc for lubuntu? I think that is what the OP is aking.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Thank you for your post, however, it seems not to be a real answer. It would probably serve better as a comment.

Comment: You're right! Sorry  ;)   new here.....

Comment: No problem, you can still convert it to a comment, or ask a new question.